# Why \substack doesn't honor the horizontal spaces around its argument?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, substack

The following MCE points out that `\substack` doesn't honor the horizontal spaces around its argument:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  (ab=0)                        \iff                     (a=0\text{ or } b=0)\\
  (ab=0) \substack{\displaystyle\iff\\\displaystyle\iff} (a=0\text{ or } b=0)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is it the case and how to retrieve the original spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first look at the definition of `\iff` in `amsmath.sty`, namely

```
\renewcommand{\iff}{\DOTSB\;\Longleftrightarrow\;}
```

Now you can define a `\doubleiff` command along the same lines, rather than abusing `\substack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Doublelongleftrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \mathsurround=0pt
      \ialign{%
        ##\cr
        \noalign{\vspace{0.25ex}}
        $\Longleftrightarrow$\cr
        \noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}
        $\Longleftrightarrow$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\doubleiff}{\DOTSB\;\Doublelongleftrightarrow\;}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  (ab=0) \iff       (a=0\text{ or } b=0)\\
  (ab=0) \doubleiff (a=0\text{ or } b=0)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note.** The `\vspace` instructions are needed because of the peculiar bounding boxes of arrows in the Computer Modern fonts. Different math fonts may not need them or need different spacings.

Comment: Indeed but I probably oversimplified my MCE: my use case doesn't involve the same symbol in the two lines of the stack (sorry for that!). I have edited my question.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé You shouldn't change your question as to invalidate the existing answers. Please roll back and ask a new question.

Comment: Eventually, no need for a new question! :)